# Joining homogeneous parts of the sentence

Tags: complex-sentences

How can I join homogeneous parts of a sentence that determine each other? Can I use commas or should I also use some linking words such as *that is*?

> **Example:**
>
> *By “circumstances” I mean not just the world around, but the society, (that is) the mob able to make anyone behave in any way, the mob that
>   influences on our decisions, actions and individuality.*

Comment: You _can_ use either, but the result is a pig of a sentence to read. You will be better off splitting your example (for example) into 2 sentences

Comment: I'm having difficulty approaching this example. Try jamming some semicolons in there.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is ideally suited to joining an elaborative clause in a sentence already riddled with commas.  As a copy editor I would write:

> By “circumstances” I mean not just the world around, but the society: the mob able to make anyone behave in any way, the mob that influences on our decisions, actions and individuality.

(I would also replace the penultimate comma with a semi-colon.)